# Does Tennessee have anything like a principal residence exemption?

Tags: united-states, property-taxes, michigan, tennessee

I just moved from Tennessee to Michigan. We are leasing the place in TN to a friend and purchased a new primary residence in Michigan. In Michigan, we have a [principal residence exemption](http://www.michigan.gov/taxes/0,4676,7-238-43535_43539-210891--,00.html) which means we pay far less for our primary residence.

However, I believe Michigan requires that we give up any exemption like this in other states. Is there anything I might need to rescind in TN? When searching for residency exemptions, I mainly came across [bankruptcy homestead exemption](https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/tennessee-bankruptcy-homestead-exemption.html) and exemptions on property taxes for seniors.

**Does TN have any property tax exemption for a primary residence?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no homestead property tax exemption in TN.

According to the [TN comptroller site](https://www.comptroller.tn.gov/sboe/sbptxov.asp):

> Exemptions
>
> Exemptions are available for religious, charitable, scientific, and
>   nonprofit educational uses, governmental property, and cemeteries.
>   Most nongovernmental exemptions require a one-time application and
>   approval by the State Board of Equalization (615/401-7883) and there
>   is a May 20 application deadline. **There is no "homestead" exemption**,
>   but low income elderly and disabled persons and disabled veterans may
>   qualify for a rebate of taxes on a specified portion of the value of
>   property used as their residence. Business inventories held for sale
>   or exchange by merchants subject to the business gross receipts tax,
>   are not assessable. Farm and residential tangible personal property
>   are not assessable.